# N or N+1 Frequency Bins Returned From FFT

Tags: python, scipy, fft

In the documentation for the scipy fft function (scipy.fftpack.fft) it reads "The packing of the result is “standard”: If A = fft(a, n), then A[0] contains the zero-frequency term, A[1:n/2] contains the positive-frequency terms, and A[n/2:] contains the negative-frequency terms". I think this means that if one has a sampling frequency of 10,000Hz and wants to transform 1,000 samples, then one passes an array to the fft function which spans [0:999] and the result has 500 real values from dc to 5,000Hz in array elements [0:499]. With element [0] being dc, element [1] being a bin between 10Hz to 20Hz and element [499] being a bin between 4,990 to 5,000 Hz. Have I got these bin values correct?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't try it to know. Pick another software that you're familiar with (Mathematica, Matlab, etc), and do the same transformation. Besides the scaling factor that comes from the transformation convention (frequency vs angular frequency), everything else should look the same.

Comment: See [this page of the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html).